# How to get the ID from user tweet that is tweeted with the "standard" tweet button

Tags: javascript, api, twitter, tweets

Twitter allows you to easily provide users the opportunity to share your content sharing it in a tweet. You can do this as easy as by just adding a link with this code in your HTML:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=test"> Click here to tweet "test" </a>
```

I really need to get the ID coming out of this tweet if the user actually does tweet. I want to retweet the tweet automatically once its tweeted.

Comment: I would think you are going to need to use Twitter's API to do this.

Comment: That would be fine, what would you suggest that I should do in the Twitter API flow?

Comment: Look here. https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/javascript-api/overview

Depending on your needs, you might get more functionality using a server side language.

Comment: Would a solution be for a user to login and once they try to tweet from the frontend the backend starts watching for tweets from that user with specific text?

Comment: No, a solution would be to use an API from Twitter.

Answer (score 0):

Conclusion: not possible, need to try and do it through the Twitter API by first making the user log-in. I'll update my answer once I'm done to show how I've done it.

Comment: Make sure you review the Twitter Automation Rules - they prohibit this kind of automatic behaviour. https://help.twitter.com/en/rules-and-policies/twitter-automation